# I am trying to render an array inside an object in React. I have a departments.json file that I have imported into my app.jsx as Data

Tags: arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am in React. I have a `departments.json` file that I am pulling my data from:
`import Data from "./departments.json"`

My information is an array of objects and within each object, I have a key with an array of multiple values. It is these values that I am trying to render as separate divs.

I have used .map to render, but it displays all of the values in one div for each object grouped together. I am really needing these values in their own div. So multiple divs are grouped per object. This is the output:

[image]

Component:

```
import Data from "./departments.json";
import Info from "./students.json";

function App() {

  console.log(Info)
  console.log(Data)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul className="filtered-student">
        {Info.map(function(student, index){
          return (
            <li key={student.id}>
              <span className="name">{[`${student.familyName}, ${student.givenName}`]}</span>
              <span className="dob">DOB: <span className="value">{student.dob}</span></span>
              <span className="admit-date">Admitted: <span className="value">{student.admitDate}</span></span>
              <span className="grad-date">Anticipated Graduation: <span className="value">{student.anticipatedGraduationDate}</span></span>
              <span className="mentor">Mentor: <span className="value">{[student.mentor.familyName, student.mentor.givenName]}</span></span>
            </li>    
          )
        })}
      </ul>
      <div className="filtered-department">
        {Data.map(function(department, index){
          return (    
            <div key={index} className="dept-name">{department.subjects}</div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

The JSON file:

```
[{
        "name": "Architecture and History of Art",
        "subjects": [
            "Painting",
            "Sculpture",
            "Architecture",
            "Drawing, printing, photography, collage and film",
            "The art and architecture of antiquity",
            "Art, religion and society",
            "Art, society and politics"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Physical Education",
        "subjects": [
            "Anatomy and physiology",
            "Social, cultural and ethical influences",
            "Skill acquisition and psychology",
            "Health, fitness and training"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Physics",
        "subjects": [
            "Physical quantities and units",
            "Measurement techniques",
            "Dynamics",
            "Forces, density and pressure",
            "Work, energy and power",
            "Deformation of solids",
            "Waves",
            "Superposition",
            "Electric fields",
            "Current of electricity",
            "D.C. circuits",
            "Particle and nuclear physics"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Εlectrical & Electronics Engineering",
        "subjects": [
            "Circuit Theory & Networks",
            "Electrical & Electronic Measurement",
            "Data Structure & Algorithms",
            "Materials Science",
            "Mathematics",
            "Numerical Methods & Programming",
            "Computer Organization & Architecture",
            "Technical Report writing"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Computer Science",
        "subjects": [
            "Information representation",
            "Communication and Internet technologies",
            "Hardware",
            "Processor fundamentals",
            "System software",
            "Security, privacy and data integrity",
            "Ethics and ownership",
            "Database and data modelling",
            "Algorithm design and problem-solving",
            "Data representation",
            "Programming",
            "Software development",
            "Monitoring and control systems"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand correctly what you need, but try this:

```
<div className="App">
  <ul className="filtered-student">
    {Info.map((student) => (
        <li key={student.id}>
          <span className="name">
            {[`${student.familyName}, ${student.givenName}`]}
          </span>
          <span className="dob">
            DOB: <span className="value">{student.dob}</span>
          </span>
          <span className="admit-date">
            Admitted: <span className="value">{student.admitDate}</span>
          </span>
          <span className="grad-date">
            Anticipated Graduation:{' '}
            <span className="value">
              {student.anticipatedGraduationDate}
            </span>
          </span>
          <span className="mentor">
            Mentor:{' '}
            <span className="value">
              {[student.mentor.familyName, student.mentor.givenName]}
            </span>
          </span>
        </li>
    ))}
  </ul>

  <div className="filtered-department">
    {Data.map((department) => (
        <div key={department.name} className="dept-name">
          {department.subjects.map((subject) => <div>{subject}</div>)}
        </div>
    ))}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much. worked great! I had just fallen too deep in the rabbit hole and was overthinking things. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Oh man, so to render these into their respective objects, Would I then just nest this map into the department name map?

Comment: I'm happy to help, Yep